# What's the difference in functionality between these two blocks of code?

Tags: erlang

First:

```
-module(some_mod).
-compile(export_all).

some_fun() ->
    fun f/0.

f() ->
    ok.
```

Second:

```
-module(some_mod).
-compile(export_all).

some_fun() ->
    fun ?MODULE:f/0.

f() ->
    ok.
```

I encountered this change during a hot code upgrade. What is the the difference between `fun ?MODULE:f/0` and `fun f/0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Erlang documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#fun_info-1):

> - A fun created by `fun M:F/A` is called an **external fun**. Calling it will always call the function `F` with arity `A` in the latest code for module `M`. Notice that module `M` does not even need to be loaded when the fun `fun M:F/A` is created.
> - All other funs are called **local fun**. When a local fun is called, the same version of the code that created the fun is called (even if a newer version of the module has been loaded).

They have different behaviours in code upgrading as the documentation says. Your first module uses a local function (`fun f/0`) and the second one uses an external function (`fun ?MODULE:f/0` which in preprocessing replaced with `fun some_mod:f/0`).

So if you upgrade your first module (which uses local function), the processes that are using `some_fun` function, don't use the newer version. But if you upgrade the second module (which uses external function), the latest version of code will be called whenever `some_fun` is called from inside processes which were spawned even before the loading of new version.

---

**Notice:** There can be just two versions of a module, **old** and **new**. If a third version of the module is loaded, the code server removes (purges) the old code and any processes lingering in it is terminated.

Comment: In fact, if a third version of the module is loaded, any process that holds on to a reference to a fun in the old code (in the `fun f/0` case) is also terminated.

Answer (score 1):

`?MODULE` is a pre-defined macro which expands to current module name. In your case it will expand to `some_mod`. Referring to `fun f/0` as `fun ?MODULE:f/0` ensures that a newer version `f/0` would be used whenever new compiled and loaded version of `some_mod` is available.